# Hub Tiles animation "semi expanded" broken

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have an issue with the Windows Phone toolkit's hub tile.

All my hub tiles disappear when the animation state change to "semi expanded" (The one where half the icon + the text is visible). After a while the will change their animation state to different one and thetext or the right images  show up as you expect them to.

It works in the emulator but not on my Lumia 800 and in the XAML preview of VS. Programming for WP 7.5 with VS 2010 on Win7 x64.

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,12">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <toolkit:HubTile 
                    Grid.Row="1" 
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="12,12,0,0"
                    Title="Brew &#13;House"
                    Source=""
                    Tap="HubTile_Tap" 
                    Name="BrewHouseTile">
            </toolkit:HubTile>
            <toolkit:HubTile 
                    Grid.Row="1" 
                    Grid.Column="1" 
                    Margin="12,12,0,0"
                    Title="Hops" 
                    Source="/BrewingApp;component/Images/icon_hops_big.png"
                    Tap="HubTile_Tap" 
                    Name="HopsTile" />
                <toolkit:HubTile 
                    Grid.Row="2" 
                    Grid.Column="0" 
                    Margin="12,12,0,0"
                    Title="Convert &#13;Units" 
                    Tap="HubTile_Tap"
                    Source="/BrewingApp;component/Images/icon_scales_big.png"
                    Name="ConvertersTile" />

              ... more Hub Tiles
            </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

[image: Hub Tiles disappear]
[image: Hub Tiles show up correctly]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually a bug in the Windows Phone toolkit. Upon resizing of the Hub Tiles the width and height get calculated again. This calculation uses a Float.TryParse() method that relies on a CultureSetting. However, when not set to EN-US this break. There is an issue on Codeplex with a quickfix:

http://phone.codeplex.com/workitem/10602

Answer (score 1):

This has exactly happened to me.

To resolve the bug:

1. You need to download the toolkit sources from here: http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/80797#
2. Modify the HubTileConverters.cs as it´s said in http://phone.codeplex.com/workitem/10602
3. And then compile. The dll file will be in the Bin ->Debug or Bin->Release depending if you compiled in debug or device mode.

You use this new dll fixed and works perfectly.